# jQuery UI Tabs And Dialog - How to confirm switching tabs with confirm based on the Dialog plugin?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, tabs, confirm

So, the goal is to confirm switching to another UI tab using UI Dialog plugin.
Using common confirm method is simple:

```
jQuery("#tabsContainer").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        return confirm("Some confirmation message...");
    }
});
```

but how to to achieve same behavior using Dialog modal box?

I think I have to call:

```
jQuery("#tabsContainer").tabs("select", ui.index);
```

on the "ok callback" but this is not working as I expected. Also - there are no errors being reported...

```
jQuery("#tabsContainer").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery("#dialogContainer").dialog({
            buttons: {
                'Ok': function() {
                    jQuery("#tabsContainer").tabs("select", ui.index);
                },
                Cancel: function() { return; }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of your problem is that `window.confirm` is blocking and jQuery UI's dialog is not.  You can get around this by structuring your code differently.  Here's one of many possible approaches:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery('#tabsContainer').tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
            // only allow a new tab to be selected if the
            // confirmation dialog is currently open.  if it's
            // not currently open, cancel the switch and show
            // the confirmation dialog.
            if (!jQuery('#dialogContainer').dialog('isOpen')) {
                $('#dialogContainer')
                    .data('tabId', ui.index)
                    .dialog('open');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    jQuery('#dialogContainer').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            'Ok': function() {
                 // a new tab must be selected before
                 // the confirmation dialog is closed
                 var tabId = $(this).data('tabId');
                 $('#tabsContainer').tabs('select', tabId);
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             },
             'Cancel': function() {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don' think the lack of blocking in ui dialog causing the problem, it's rather something about calls order maybe? Never mind, your code works like a charm, so big thanks :)